# How to stop automatically login to the created account in aspnet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here I am using asp.net configuration and mvc model. I have created a form to create users with the help of createUserWizard .NET component. After creating the user it automatically logs with the created user. How to stop this?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CreateUserWizard has a property called LoginCreatedUser.
The default value of it is true.Simply change that to false. 
Hope you've got the answer :)